# Converting Multiset Count into a List Java

Tags: java, processing, guava, multiset

Is there any way to pull the count from a `Multiset` into a list?

```
String[] data = loadStrings("data/data.txt"); 

Multiset<String> myMultiset = ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(data);

for (String word : Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset).elementSet()) {
    System.out.println(word + ": " + myMultiset.count(word));
    // ...
}
```

As it stands I can output the most commonly occurring words into the console in Processing. I was wondering if it is at all possible to add the corresponding words and their count into an array or a list. I have tried like so:

```
for (String word : Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset).elementSet()) {
    float a[] = myMultiset.count(word);
}
```

but only received errors stating I cannot convert an `int` to a `float[]`

Is this even possible? Am I going about it all wrong? I've never used `Multiset`s before so any help would be really useful

UPDATE:
I have used this to get a copy of the highest count but am unable to convert it into a list.

```
Multiset<String> sortedList = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [`Multiset.entrySet()` docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#entrySet()):

> Returns a view of the contents of this multiset, grouped into Multiset.Entry instances, each providing an element of the multiset and the count of that element.

So, i.e. to get the top 5 most occurring owrds, I'd loop over the `entrySet()`:

```
ImmutableMultiset<String> top = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset);

Iterator<Multiset.Entry<String>> it = top.entrySet().iterator();

for (int i = 0; (i < 5) && it.hasNext(); i++) {
    Multiset.Entry<String> entry = it.next();

    String word = entry.getElement();
    int count = entry.getCount();

    // do something fancy with word and count...
}
```

I'm assuming you need to show the top 5 most occurring words and their frequencies. If you only need the words, just use [`asList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html#asList()) method:

```
ImmutableMultiset<String> top = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset);

ImmutableList<String> list = top.asList();
```

and iterate over `list` to get the first 5 elements.

Comment: Wow thanks for taking the time :), you think its possibly easier to just use a map?

Comment: Main reason for doing this is i thought it would be easy to represent the values in a bar chart in processing this way...

Comment: @Nebbyyy I think you could perfectly use a map for that. Just use a `LinkedHashMap`, because it preserves insertion order. This way, you'll have the top word first, then the second topmost word, etc. Just use the keys (which hold the words) for the X axis and the values (which holds the frequencies) for the Y axis. I'll edit my answer so that it's clear that a `LinkedHashMap` should be used.

Comment: There's nothing a map would do that you couldn't just use the `Multiset` for directly.  If you want to preserve insertion order, use a `LinkedHashMultiset` -- or just keep using the multiset returned by `copyHighestCountFirst` without copying it.  Copying it seems honestly pointless.

Comment: @LouisWasserman How do you get the collection of the frequencies?

Comment: There's no view for that collection directly, but what do you actually want to do with it?  e.g. you could always iterate over the `entrySet`, and you can easily get the total count, etc. and everything else you need for the actual histogram that way.

Comment: What im trying to do is display the top 5 most occurring words in a bar chart when pulling the data from twitter into a .txt file

Comment: @Nebbyyy Iterate de `ImmutableMultiSet` only 5 times with a classic `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`

Comment: ive had to redo it as ive been getting syntax error with the code. at the for loop an error on token"<",

Comment: @Nebbyyy Fixed. It's `Multiset` (instead of `MultiSet`) (the 's' from set must be lowercase).

Comment: oh my god you life saver, can't believe i missed that, you are a true gent

Comment: @Nebbyyy It was my fault! Your code was OK from the beginning. I just didn't try the code I posted (my bad!), so I had that syntax error. Hope everything works well now that it's fixed.

Comment: @Nebbyyy Which version of java are you using?

Comment: I'm still receiving the error I just checked online and im on version 8 Update 40, and using processing 2.2.1. Do you think it might be an issue because of my java version as the error is simply with Multiset.Entry<String>> using the "<"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73847/discussion-between-magnamag-and-nebbyyy).